# how to run a while loop several time

Tags: java, arrays

I have tring to solve this task, but i can not run while loop more than 1 time .

In this task you will solve what we call the birthday problem. Suppose that we have an empty classroom. students
coming into the classroom one by one. We assume that each
student has a random birthday between 0 and 365, where 0
represents January 1st and 364 represents last
December. The problem consists in finding out the average of
the number of students who must enter the classroom so that
two students have a birthday on the same day.
Tip: run a large number of simulations. For each simulation
use an array to compare random birthdays too
students.

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count;
        boolean[] used;

        used = new boolean[365];

        count = 0;

        while (true) {
            int birthday;  // The selected birthday.
            birthday = (int) (Math.random() * 365);
            count++;
            if (used[birthday]) {
                // This day was found before; It's a duplicate.
                break; }

            used[birthday] = true; }
        System.out.println("A duplicate birthday was found after "
                + count + " kids came to the class.");


      //  double[] arr = {Numbers};
       // double total = 0;

        //for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
           // total = total + arr[i];
        //}



        //double average = total / arr.length;


       // System.out.format("The average is: %", average);

    }
```

Comment: Hi Mahmood, it would be good if you could make a simpler piece of code to demonstrate the problem. If the question is about how to nest loops, then all the details of the simulation aren't really relevant and make it complicated.

Comment: It seems you have forgotten to ask a question. I assume that is the reason you came to this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just surround the assignment and count within a for loop, for the number of simuations.

for (int simulation = 0; simulation < 100000; simulation++) {
    ......
}

And after every break of the while loop, add the count to another variable. Once all your simulations are done, divide the count by the number of simulations to get the average "Birthday Problem" probability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) around the simulation.

I would suggest putting the simulation code into a separate method to make things clearer. Here's a complete example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int runs = 100000;
    long studentsNeeded = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        studentsNeeded += studentsNeededBeforeWeFoundASharedBirthday();
    }
    double meanStudentsNeeded = (double) studentsNeeded / runs;
    System.out.println(String.format("After %d runs, it took %.2f students on "
            + "average before we found a shared birthday.", runs, meanStudentsNeeded));
}

private static int studentsNeededBeforeWeFoundASharedBirthday() {
    Random r = new Random();
    boolean[] used = new boolean[365];
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        count++;
        int birthday = r.nextInt(365);
        if (used[birthday]) {
            break;
        }
        used[birthday] = true;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Prints:

> After 100000 runs, it took 24.61 students on average before we found a shared birthday.